# AJAX requests when customer change attribute of configurable product

Tags: magento2, php, magento-2.1

I want to make AJAX requests when customer change attribute of configurable product.

For example - he changes color. 
AJAX request asking backend how many items (qty) are available for this SKU.
Backend checks qty and depends of number make response like “In stock”, “Only 1 left in stock”, “Out of stock”.

How to attach custom AJAX query to product page and how to implement checking qty of requested product (sku)?

Comment: Hi, I am looking for same function, did you found any solution on that? Thank you

Comment: Hi! I'm still looking for best solution but we're using other method - I'm overriding swatch-renderer.js in custom theme and manipulating this.options.jsonSwatchConfig which is coming from my extended Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable object.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make AJAX requests when customer change attribute of
> configurable product.

Similar functionality has already been implemented out of the box for some elements of the product. However, this is not done with an AJAX request. Perhaps this approach will work for you.

Out of the box, when choosing options, *images*, *price*, etc will change, but custom attributes.

In order to display the custom attribute or other info of the selected product, you can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()` where you need to add missing custom attribute for each simple product.

Switching custom attribute when selecting an option can be implemented in `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` and `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js` depending on the [type of attribute](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html#product-variation-attribute-requirements).

---

I made free `VCT Product Info Switcher` module which update some attributes.